# How to format DML or DDL SQL output for double join?

Tags: sql, join, double, output

I am trying to determine the average $ amount per date between two types of customers: Asian and Non-Asian. There are 3 separate tables (attached image file shows a sample),

```
user_description
account_description
transaction_description
```

which contain data regarding the customer type, whether they are Asian or non-Asian, and the amount they paid on a specific transaction date. Long story short, I have the correct results, but my output is not quite ideal. Let's take for instance, the sample schema (below is a script to populate this sample, as well as an image file.) Specifically, my **desired output** is:

```
transaction_date    Average Amount per Asian Customer   Average amount per Non-Asian Customer
10/12/1998          31.66                               35
10/31/2013          0                                   30
```

So for instance, this output is saying that for the date 10/31/1998, the average amount paid for by an Asian customer was $31.66, while the average amount per Non-Asian customer was $35.

My **current output** shows the correct information, but it splits the average amount by date as well! So, the output I get is shown below:

```
transaction_date    Average Amount per Asian Customer   Average amount per Non-Asian Customer
10/12/1998          31.66                               0
10/12/1998          0                                   35
10/31/2013          0                                   30
```

**My question is: how can I format the results output to display similar to the desired output, given my code already has double join? Do I need to re-write the code completely to get the desired view, or is there a way I can do it without DDL (creating a temporary view, etc)?**

I've already tried doing a double join or pivot on the table, but no luck. I'm using SQLfiddle as my SQL editor btw, for testing.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJnbs.png)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Appendix**

Code/SQL query

```
select  transaction_date, 
(case when (asian_status = 'No')
then sum(amount)/count(distinct(transactions.customer_id))
else 0
end) as "Average Amount per Non-Asian Customer",
(case when (asian_status = 'Yes')
then sum(amount)/count(distinct(transactions.customer_id))
else 0
end) as "Average Amount per Asian Customer"
from
(user_description join account_description on
user_description.account_id = account_description.account_id) join
transactions on transactions.customer_id = user_description.customer_id
group by transaction_date, asian_status
order by transaction_date;
```

Code for Population:

```
CREATE TABLE user_description (customer_id INTEGER, account_id INTEGER);
CREATE TABLE account_description (account_id INTEGER, credit_source TEXT, asian_status TEXT);
CREATE TABLE transactions (transaction_date DATE, customer_id INTEGER, service_type TEXT, amount INTEGER);

INSERT INTO user_description (customer_id, account_id) VALUES (1, 15);
INSERT INTO user_description (customer_id, account_id) VALUES (2, 17);
INSERT INTO user_description (customer_id, account_id) VALUES (3, 23);
INSERT INTO user_description (customer_id, account_id) VALUES (4, 28);
INSERT INTO user_description (customer_id, account_id) VALUES (5, 28);
INSERT INTO user_description (customer_id, account_id) VALUES (6, 23);

INSERT INTO account_description (account_id, credit_source, asian_status) VALUES (15, 'Savings', 'Yes');
INSERT INTO account_description (account_id, credit_source, asian_status) VALUES (17, 'Checkings', 'No');
INSERT INTO account_description (account_id, credit_source, asian_status) VALUES (23, 'Savings', 'No');
INSERT INTO account_description (account_id, credit_source, asian_status) VALUES (28, 'Debit', 'Yes');

INSERT INTO transactions (transaction_date, customer_id, service_type, amount) VALUES ('2011-10-14', 2, 'ATM', 30);
INSERT INTO transactions (transaction_date, customer_id, service_type, amount) VALUES ('1998-10-12', 2, 'bank', 25);
INSERT INTO transactions (transaction_date, customer_id, service_type, amount) VALUES ('1998-10-12', 1, 'online', 45);
INSERT INTO transactions (transaction_date, customer_id, service_type, amount) VALUES ('1998-10-12', 1, 'online', 10);
INSERT INTO transactions (transaction_date, customer_id, service_type, amount) VALUES ('1998-10-12', 3, 'ATM', 20);
INSERT INTO transactions (transaction_date, customer_id, service_type, amount) VALUES ('1998-10-12', 4, 'bank', 15);
INSERT INTO transactions (transaction_date, customer_id, service_type, amount) VALUES ('1998-10-12', 5, 'ATM', 25);
INSERT INTO transactions (transaction_date, customer_id, service_type, amount) VALUES ('1998-10-12', 6, 'bank', 60);
```